# How to filter rows of a pandas df using the columns value as the key to a dictionary based on its returned value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe which I need to filter rows out when the value returned by a dictionary using the value of the specific column is used as a dictionary key to return the keys value.

I have been able to filter the rows based on the columns value but when i try to use the columns value in a dictionary in a similar fashion iit returns an error.

```sh
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

```py
indexNames = df[ accounting_type_dict[df['fund_id']] == 'ETFs' ].index
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `map` then filter

```
newdf=df[df['fund_id'].map(accounting_type_dict) == 'ETFs'].copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing the column with the corresponding values from the dict. (You may need to use map instead of replace depending on how large the DataFrame is.)

```
indexNames = df[ df['fund_id'].replace(accounting_type_dict) == 'ETFs' ].index
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```